# How Much Database Space do Content Revisions take up?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

We all know that Joomla, since v3.2 offers content versioning, by means of saving previous copies of articles while editing them.

In Content | Articles | Options | Editing Layout tab we have following option:

[image]

to Enable Versions (default disabled) and Maximum number of them (default 10).

I was searching the Net high and low, but was unable to find any reference to how much will database space increase by enabling Article Versions? My educated guess would be article HTML size in bytes (character count) multiplied by number of saved versions (up to max number) multiplied by number of articles.

Does anyone know exactly how much database space will be taken by content revisions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it, there is no exact answer to your Q, because equation has variables of unknown values. Article's character counts differ from article to article, and number of saved copies is different for each article.

Mathematicaly speaking, I would opt for median statistic value of:

`xx_content table size in bytes × 5`

5 being median number of content revisions for all articles alltogether.

Depending of total size of all articles, it might sum up pretty high.